# Fastify-compress ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED on Requests

Tags: compression, gzip, nestjs, fastify

I'm using fastify-compress in my NestJS application like so...

```
nestApp.register(compression.default, { threshold: 10240, encodings: ['gzip', 'deflate'] });
```

Looking at the requests in the browser, I am seeing the following error...

```
ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200 (OK)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: did you happen to get a solution, I just ran across the problem, and removing fastify-compress prevented the error, but didn't really solve the issue.